# Extract first column of a 2D list along with indices in a single line

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

How would you short these two list comprehension to one line? I would like to code as one line. My way seems too long. I feel like there is another way to code it.

```
y = [array[i][0] for i in range(len(array))]
x = [i for i in range(len(array))]

x, y = [i for i in range(len(array))], [array[i][0] for i in range(len(array))]
```

Comment: This can definitely be made more concise, but stuffing it into one line seems misguided.

Comment: you can use `enumerate` to accomplish this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you want to extract the first column of a 2D list along with it's indices, you'd use `enumerate` with inverse-`zip` unpacking:

```
array = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
x, y = zip(*enumerate([r[0] for r in array]))
```

```
print(x)
(0, 1, 2)

print(y)
(1, 4, 7)
```

`x` is the index, and `y` is the row vector. As seen above, this method results in your data being extracted out as *`tuple`s* (not `list`s), and will fail when `array` is empty.

So, as @user2357112 said in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112), please don't endeavour to shove *all* your code into one line – do it only when it can be done and makes sense to do so.

Furthermore, to extend the discussion in comments, the *best* way to do this would be to follow a 2-step approach as shown by @Rakesh in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49578625/4909087):

```
x = list(range(len(array)))
y = [r[0] for r in array]
```

```
print(x)
[0, 1, 2]

print(y)
[1, 4, 7]
```

This doesn't suffer from the drawbacks mentioned above.

Comment: This creates tuples, and it fails for an empty `array`. Fixing the empty array bug makes the code bulky again.

Comment: @user2357112 that's a good point, thanks. Your comment really drives it home -- this shouldn't be done if it introduces complications like that.

Comment: @VuralErdogan Sure, as long as you keep in mind what user2357112 said. Don't _always_ try to do this -- in fact, I'd recommend Rakesh's answer because it handles corner cases better.

Comment: @VuralErdogan No, no it's not a good way. Forget about it and do it in two lines instead.

Comment: Oh sure, I mean that I will use the other way for readability.

Comment: You seem to have removed the remark about failing on empty input; was that an accident? (The `zip` snippet [does fail](https://ideone.com/jRZUih) on empty input.)

Comment: @user2357112 It definitely was a mistake, thank you! Yes, I tested it and it indeed will fail.

Answer (score 2):

This should help

```
x = range(len(array))    #range returns  list
y = [i[0] for i in array]    #you can access the element in the list without range or len
```

Comment: `range` returns a list on Python 2, anyway. If you're on Python 3, and you really need a list object, you can call `list` on the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
x, y = list(map(list, zip(*[(i, r[0]) for i, r in enumerate(a)]))) or ([], [])
```

disclaimer: I think it's a situation where one-liner-ness is a bad thing.